# Writing and transferring events between services (AWS)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

We have a php service that need to log data very fast(handles 1000 clients per second. with each one writing a record to the log. So 1000 writes per second) and then send that logged data in near realtime to another service. We are using AWS. How would you transfer the data to another amazon service?
Should we use a database(sync writing will block the php requests, no?) Should we use something like amazon SQS or any other amazon solution?

Also, we are using redshift to query the data.
Thanks

So as suggested here by people, we see a few possible solutions:
1. Node.js with amazon kinesis
2. Node.js with amazon sqs
3. Node.js writing to s3 with lambda processing it
4. We are using in one of our servers a solution of writing to a local mongodb and flushing in bulk every few minutes to s3 (we could change it to seconds)

What are the pros/cons of each solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Network latency is long than a millisecond.  I don't think this is possible.

Comment: We can live with a few seconds delay (for the other service)

Answer (score 3):

Amazon has a perfect product for your use case.  Kinesis

> Amazon Kinesis can continuously capture and store terabytes of data
>   per hour from hundreds of thousands of sources such as website
>   clickstreams, financial transactions, social media feeds, IT logs, and
>   location-tracking events.
>
> Source: http://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/

Your 1000 writes per second is the base unit, a Shard.  You could probably start with 1 and then add a 2nd if your demand increases.

> Shard is the base throughput unit of an Amazon Kinesis stream. One
>   shard provides a capacity of 1MB/sec data input and 2MB/sec data
>   output. One shard can support up to 1000 PUT records per second. You
>   specify the number of shards needed within your stream based on your
>   throughput requirements. You are charged for each shard at an hourly
>   rate.

Comment: Where do you see that it's expensive? How did you calculate?

Comment: Pricing is here.  http://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/pricing/   For the 1 shard I described at 1000 PUTs a second the price is ~$86.15 / mo.  Now that's if you maintain 1000 records per second for every second of the entire month and your size is 1k per put.  The base shard price is $11.16 per month then you pay for the PUTs on top.  `"Expensive" is all relative`.  Especially if you are doing 1000 ore more requests per second.

Comment: Thanks for the calculation! So yes, it's not that expensive

Answer (score 1):

You could use multiple steps, for instance you could have a very basic node.js service installed locally on the web server that accepts log entries (this will give you minimum latency and maximum throughput). Then the node.js service could transfer the log entries where you want (a db, SQS, SNS, whatever).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of s3 and lambda. 
Everyone writes the data to s3 and for every object added to s3 bucket you can have a lambda function run to process it. Both the services are very cheap and highly scalable.